# Gmail Add-On Multiple configuration

Tags: gmail-addons

I am researching building a Gmail Add-On.

We have several clients that host their own sites, plus clients that are we are hosting.

If the client is self hosted their URL is https://api.clientname.com
If the client is hosted by us the URL is https://api.company.com

Need to store that plus a few other settings in a configuration somewhere on the server like appsettings.json.

Is this possible in a Gmail Add-on using a single build and deploy method?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps.

1.Try to store the appsettings.json in some server. This should be accessible through http requests.
2.Whenever you need to access this settings, use `URLFetchApp` of the appscript to fetch the file.

You can read more about `URLFetchApp` [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Or if you would like to cache it , refer [this.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

Comment: If the appsettings are different based on client how would it know which appsettings to read?  Example I have a web server for a single client. 
That website has a connection to DB: 1.  2nd client uses the exact same web site, but points the connection to DB: 2  I can accomplish this 1 of 2 ways different domains and the server knows which domain connects to which DB or set a different Web Server and build a new appsettings.json file to read.  The code is the same I build and deploy 1 to multiple sites.  It appears that neither of these is an option in Add-Ons

Comment: In such cases , allow the user to enter the domain in UI. I faced a similar problem. I had to handle http request based on domains. To solve this , I get the domain from the user to and use it while sending http requests.

Comment: And where do you persist the domain name? Or does the user have to enter it every time they start the add-on?